# Two links for one menu item in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, menu, hyperlink, menuitem

I am making a site for a client and they would like a navigation item that has two words linking to two different places.  The item is the last one, "twitter/facebook", to the right.  Any ideas?  http://pixinkdesign.com/clients1/TedX/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the links to your template and style as required. They're not page of your site anyway so a simple link in the template should suffice.

Login to your admin panel and go to:

```
Appearance > Editor
```

and open up the `Header.php` file.

You'll see something like:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
</ul>
```

Which you can simply add to for your needs:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
  <li>
      <a href="http://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
      <a href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```